# I am doing a palindrome check in C# and I do not know why it is not working

Tags: c#

I have turned the integer into a string and reversed it, but when I run it, it keeps returning the wrong answer.

```
var x = 121;
var numba = x.ToString();
char[] strArray = numba.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(strArray);

StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder newString2 = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var item in strArray)
{
    newString.Append(item);
}

foreach(var item in numba.ToCharArray())
{
    newString2.Append(item);
}        

Console.WriteLine(newString);            
Console.WriteLine(newString2);

if(newString == newString2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("true");
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("false");
}
```

It is both printing 121. However, it is not returning `true`? is this some sort of edge case with `StringBuilder`?

Comment: What part of this (incomplete) code do you think should be causing `true` to be returned?

Comment: Your `if` comparison isn't comparing what you think it is.

Comment: You're comparing two StringBuilders to see if they are the same instance. Instead compare the strings - `if(newString.ToString() == newString2.ToString())`

Comment: You don't need a string builder anyway - you can reverse the string with `var newString2 = new string(newString.Reverse().ToArray());`

Comment: For a palindrome check, it's more efficient to simply walk the string from each end to the middle, comparing characters along the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the if statement from:

```
         if(newString == newString2)
```

to:

```
         if(newString.Equals(newString2))
```

your issue would be resolved.

When == is used on an expression of type object, it'll resolve to System.Object.ReferenceEquals.

Equals is just a virtual method and behaves as such, so the overridden version will be used (which, for string type compares the contents).

As a side note, you can also simplify your logic with code like below:

```
        var x = 121;
        var numStr = x.ToString();
        var numArray = numStr.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(numArray);
        var revStr = new string(numArray);
        Console.WriteLine(numStr + "\n" + revStr);

        if(numStr.Equals(revStr))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("false");
        }
```

It's likely not the most optimal code, but should be more manageable than your approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an "edge case" with `StringBuilder`, it simply means that the `StringBuilder` class does not override the `==` operator, so you're getting the default reference comparison between the two objects.

To get a comparison of the strings they represent, you can do the comparison on the result of calling `ToString()` on the `StringBuilder` objects:

```
 if(newString.ToString() == newString2.ToString())
```

But really it seems you're doing a lot of extra work here, to copy the string and then do a full comparison. Instead, it's simpler to just walk through the string from each end towards the middle, comparing characters along the way:

```
var x = 121;
var numba = x.ToString();

// Get the length of half the string
int halfLength = numba.Length / 2;

// Start assuming it is a palindrome
bool isPalindrome = true;

// Compare a character from the beginning of the string
// with it's corresponding character at the end. If the
// characters do not match, it's not a palindrome.
for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++)
{
    if (numba[i] != numba[numba.Length - i - 1])
    {
        // The characters don't match, it's not a palindrome
        isPalindrome = false;
        break;
    }
}

// Output the result
Console.WriteLine(isPalindrome);
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple method to check for a palindrome -

```
        static bool IsPalindrome(string inputString)
        {
            var characters = inputString.ToCharArray();
            var stringLength = characters.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length/2; i++)
            {
                if (characters[i].Equals(characters[stringLength - 1 - i]))
                    continue;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Usage

```
            var result = IsPalindrome("asdffdsa");
```

Comment: First off, this doesn't answer the question that was asked, which was for help with debugging the existing code. Second, this code has some bad programming practices; please do not teach new developers bad habits.

Comment: Next, why do you convert a string to a char array? You only use length and indexing, both of which are already supported by strings! You're allocating a block of memory for literally no reason.

Comment: Next, though it is correct to call `Equals` on a `char`, the idiomatic way to write this would be to use `==`, not `char.Equals`.

Comment: @EricLippert - Agree on the empty string and on the array, I was under the impression that it has better performance over indexing the string - but my assumption is wrong, it would appear.

Comment: Finally, I note that this does not deal with surrogate pair characters, so it is only correct for a certain subset of legal strings.